# std::string violates Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c++, single-responsibility

I recently attended a C++ talk on SOLID principles and the presenter provided `std::string` as an example that violates SRP. I wasn't quite able to comprehend why that was the case. From what I understand, `std::string` isn't a paragon for STL data structures, unlike `std::vector` etc., since it duplicates some free functions from the `<algorithm>` library like `find`, `replace`(with no customized specialization [Please correct me]), etc. but, in my opinion, it is still a cohesive bunch of functions to help manipulate strings. One possible argument I could think against it demonstrating SRP was that `std::string` allocates as well as manipulates strings, which could lead to issues mixing it with other instantiations of [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) but I'm not sure if that's an apt defect in the context of SRP. Can someone please help elaborate on why it violates SRP?

Comment: I don't think it does.  It has one responsibility: *represent a string object.*  What was the speaker's argument?

Comment: (1) Without linking to any materials from that presentation or the presenter, any argument we try to make here will just be straw man. (2) The claim elucidated by OP's best effort seems to say that OOP fundamentally violates SRP by bundling the various aspects that make up "object-ness" into a single entity. Which is valid, from a C perspective. What's wrong with `malloc` and `strchr`, after all? What's wrong with `char*` ? Different languages, different perspectives.

Comment: I remember a post here along the lines "We decided to fully enforce SRP. Our code went from 70 classes to 700. What should we do now?". SRP in the wrong hands is very dangerous.

Comment: For what it's worth, std::string's internal APIs are based on indices and counts, while the algorithms are based on iterators. Broadly speaking, people who have string code based on using indices don't want to transition it to iterators. So that's what those APIs are for.

Answer (score 8):

SRP isn't a well-defined thing. Bob Martin, the guy who came up with it is on his 5th or so attempt at defining it and it's still mostly just confusing with very little concrete points or even code.

So it all depends on who you ask. To put it differently: both sides could be argued. Not just for `string`, but for mostly *everything*.

Comment: That's why you should take everything Bob Martin says as suggestions, not edicts.

Comment: What's terrible about Bob Martin's SRP is that the David Parnas article that inspired SRP is **much clearer**.  Page 24: "We propose instead that one begins with a list of difficult design decisions or design decisions which are likely to change. Each module is then designed to hide such a decision from
the others" 
 https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/On_the_criteria_to_be_used_in_decomposing_systems_into_modules/6607958